# Categorial connection between SU(2) and SU(3)

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, lie-groups

I recall reading a proposition that there is a connection in terms and language of category theory between $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ and no other two ranks including each of the two I mentioned have a categorial connection of this kind, if at all.

My aim, to be clear, is to approach $SU(3)$ using $SU(2)$ which is easy to study and comprehend, and I cannot say the same about the 3rd rank group.

Any lead, answer, or link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Important connections between $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ would undoubtedly be mentioned in the [wiki on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group).  While their individual importance in physics is outlined there, I do not see any strong connection between the two, categorical or not.

There is, towards the bottom, a relationship $SU(n)\supset SU(p)\times SU(n-p)\times U(1)$ where $1<p<n$, which would be in some sense unique for $n=3$ given those constraints.  But if we admit this relationship as relevant then the idea that `and no other two ranks including each of the two I mentioned have a categorial connection of this kind` goes out the window.

There is, of course, a [famous connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Connection_between_SO(3)_and_SU(2)) between $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ but that is not what you've asked.

To make any more progress, we're probably going to need more hints than a half-remembered statement about the topic.

Comment: First of all thank you, more than you think. :). About the half-remembered nature I apologize, it is what it is, as Seinfeld said. There is no way on earth I mistaken $SO(3)$ with $SU(3)$ with respect, or in associative connection to $SU(2)$. The question now is can my posted question have a correct answer, namely this one? :)

Comment: Here is a list of correspondences in the light of spheres (esp. $\mathbb{S}^5,\mathbb{S}^6$):
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/journey-manifold-su2mathbbc-part/#2-Spheres
but as mentioned above, it is $SO(3)$ that is the natural partner of $SU(2).$

Comment: I remember experimenting with Anti-Hermitian $3x3$ linear space, which is the algebra of $SU(3)$, and to be imprecise any sign of resemblance shatters the previous one, which makes the idea that perhaps I did remember incorrectly highly probable. My interest is the physics application, by the way. But I want to understand it mathematically in a thorough manner, first.

Comment: @MariusS.L. I'm aware of that connection. My experience with the little I know in category theory is that it is a sort of levrage to partnerships which appear to have nothing to do with each other. And, it is modularized not only as categories but also the mathematical content. This is impressive, and i had hope :)

Comment: @user192234 Unless you get lucky and someone unearths the other half of your remembered claim, it's going to be incumbent on you to find out what your question is talking about.  If you want to use category theory, you're going to want to know what category or categories you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The generators of the Quaternions $i,j,k$ can correspond to Pauli matrices multiplied to close as a Lie Algebra for $SU(2)$, as anti-Hermitian.

$U(3)$ has $9$ generators and tensor product $SU(2)\times SU(2) \equiv U(3)$

Every finite representation can be multiplied by a phase to become an element of $SU(3)$. So

$$SU(3)\subset \frac{SU(2)\times SU(2)}{U(1)}$$

Perhpas this is an equality.

Couplets of Pauli matrices are always traceless, but need to multiply by an imaginary unit, and that representation has that

$$su(3) \subset su(2)\times isu(2) $$

This is consistent with the above, and this is a connection between the algebras, and hence between the groups.